# Define and structure JavaScripts in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**maps.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'maps',
    templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
    styles: []
})

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

    //constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

and the corresponding **maps.component.html:**

```
<h2>Location of OPMs</h2>
<style>
    #map{
        height:400px;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="initMaps.js"></script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=....&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

and the **initMaps.js:**

```
function initMap(){
    // Map options
    var options = {
        zoom:8,
        center:{lat:42.3601,lng:-71.0589}
    }
    // New map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
}
```

Loading the .html file seperately, the map is shown, however with angular framework it doesn't. How Can i define these scripts such that the map is loaded when this .html page is loaded in browser?

Comment: Script tags are blocked within components. You'll need to add it to `index.html`, or within the `scripts` array of `angular-cli.json` assuming you're using angular cli

Comment: Also, you can get the google maps type definition with `npm install --save @types/googlemaps` and import them in your app `import {} from '@types/googlemaps'`. I'd suggest adding your map initialization logic in `ngOnInit()`, to make your code more readable and maintainable. This article explains it well : https://blog.cloudboost.io/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-5-ca5f68009f29

Comment: ok thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json add es5 to lib like this:

```
"lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es5"
    ]
```